# Loading Notification In Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, notifications, spinner, loading

I want to use spinner that shows loading an image in my phonegap app, because it fetches them from the server, user must be notified.I made some search on the internet and saw that navigator.notification.loadingStart and  navigator.notification.loadingStop cannot be used anymore.I also looked at the phonegap docs but i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the plugins for phonegap over at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/

NoticationEX is what your after :

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/NotificationEx

Comment: Thanks Adam,but i could't find the necessary thing in these sites.I had to use spinner while loading images.I used the code in http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/ .